# go to www.xxxx.com/index.html when I write www.xxxx.com is it possible in web.config

Tags: visual-web-gui

go to  [www.xxxx.com/index.html](http://www.xxxx.com/index.html) when I write [www.xxxx.com](http://www.xxxx.com) is it possible in web.config file in windows visualwebgui application

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.